# Why does the mp4 from ffmpeg freeze during the last 3 seconds?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate a perfectly looping mp4 from three inputs:

1. A background png image
2. An image sequence of transparent png images with the number of particles increasing
3. Another image sequence of transparent png images with the number of particles decreasing

I'm currently trying to achieve this with two commands (I have to use 'overlay' twice). The problem is that after the second command the video (test2.mp4) freezes for the last 3 seconds. Why does it happen? ARe there any other commands I could try to use?

First command:

```sh
ffmpeg -framerate 30 \
    -pattern_type glob -i 'images/increase/*.png' \
    -framerate 30 \
    -i screens/Background.png \
    -i audio/50-White-Noise-10min.mp3 \
    -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v] overlay" \
    -preset slow -c:a copy -shortest -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

Second command:

```sh
ffmpeg -framerate 30 \
    -pattern_type glob -i 'images/decrease/*.png' \
    -i test.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v] overlay" \
    -preset slow -c:a copy -shortest -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p test2.mp4
```

Comment: Copy and paste the complete log from command #2.

Comment: You can chain overlay filters with a comma separating them. This will reduce one command. But it may not solve your problem which may have other reasons. See this for examples of overlay chaining: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do what [Rajib commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585073/why-does-the-mp4-from-ffmpeg-freeze-during-the-last-3-seconds/69595601#comment123011549_69585073): chain the overlay filters and do it all in one command:

```sh
ffmpeg -framerate 30 \
    -i screens/Background.png \
    -framerate 30 \
    -pattern_type glob -i 'images/increase/*.png' \
    -framerate 30 \
    -pattern_type glob -i 'images/decrease/*.png' \
    -i audio/50-White-Noise-10min.mp3 \
    -filter_complex "[0][1] overlay[out],[out][2] overlay" \
    -c:a copy -shortest -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p loop.mp4
```

Comment: Should be `[0][1] overlay[out];[out][2] overlay`. Filterchains are to be separated by semi-colon, not comma. See [FFmpeg Filtering Syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1).